# Count Max using multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to get a maximum count of items in a table within a column called 'Code'.

I have data in my table like this:

```
ID  Contact Date        Service     Code            Tech    Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4   Code5
1   306     5/8/2009    Individual  30751 3004      Mike    30751   3004    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   306     5/13/2009   Individual  30751 3004      Mike    30751   3004    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   308     4/17/2009   Testing     29631           Keith   29631   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   318     4/20/2009   Individual  29633           Carol   29633   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   318     4/27/2009   Individual  29633           Carol   29633   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
6   318     4/13/2009   Individual  29633           Carol   29633   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
7   318     5/4/2009    Individual  29633           Carol   29633   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   318     5/11/2009   Individual  29633           Carol   29633   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   320     4/27/2009   Office      5781 3004 4019  Ed      5781    3004    4019    NULL    NULL
10  324     4/17/2009   Individual  3004            Julie   3004    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
11  324     2/20/2009   Individual  3004            Julie   3004    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12  324     4/3/2009    Individual  3004            Julie   3004    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
13  325     5/19/2009   Interview   3090            Max     3090    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Notice the Code column sometimes has more than one item separated by a space.  In that case, the second code goes into the Code2 column and if there is a third code it will go into the Code3 column.

Currently we are using a query like this to find the most common Code, however, it is not accurate for the rows that have more than one item in the Code column.

```
SELECT *    FROM (  SELECT ID,
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN dd1.allowed = 1 AND dd1.co_allowed = 1 THEN Code1 
                                        WHEN dd2.allowed = 1 AND dd2.co_allowed = 1 THEN Code2
                                        WHEN dd3.allowed = 1 AND dd3.co_allowed = 1 THEN Code3
                                    END AS Code,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNum
                                FROM MC
                                    LEFT JOIN ReferenceTables.dbo.dim_code dd1 ON MC.Code1 = dd1.no_decimal
                                    LEFT JOIN ReferenceTables.dbo.dim_code dd2 ON MC.Code2 = dd2.no_decimal
                                    LEFT JOIN ReferenceTables.dbo.dim_code dd3 ON MC.Code3 = dd3.no_decimal
                                WHERE (dd1.allowed = 1 AND dd1.co_allowed = 1)
                                    OR (dd2.allowed = 1 AND dd2.co_allowed = 1)
                                    OR (dd3.allowed = 1 AND dd3.co_allowed = 1) ) x 
                        WHERE RowNum = 1
```

How would I make this accurately count the items using the Code1, Code2, Code3, and Code4 columns?  Or is there a way to put all those codes into one column and count that way?  I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be to remove the "Code" column from this table all together, and add a Service_X_Code table.

```
create table Service_X_code
(service_id int not null,
 code integer)
```

That table could model your many to many relationship for service to codes.  Then a simple:

```
 select count(*), code
 from service_x_code
 group by code
```

Your problem is coming from your mis modelled data.  Fix your data and your query is easy.